# Discretization of a region for NDSolve using

Tags: differential-equations, programming, mesh, finite-element-method, discretization

I would like to mesh the region below in order to use it for a calculation by means of NDSolve. Could anyone help me to discretize this region for NDSolve using. Thank you very much.

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

Rwg=7.0; RLiner=8.0; RRib=8.5; RExt=9.0; Theta1=0.0227; Theta2=0.00916;

Ω=ImplicitRegion[
    !(x^2 + y^2>RLiner^2 && x^2 + y^2< RRib^2 && 0=0 && x^2 + y^2>=Rwg^2 && x^2 + y^2<=RExt^2 && y<=x Tan[Theta1]),{x, y}];

Comment: Aside from the fact that you have now included `0=0` in your list of conditions, **how is this different from your last post?**

Comment: No difference. I just was trying to give more visibility to my question.